# Does haproxy cache content by default?

Tags: haproxy

We are currently using haproxy in round-robin mode distribute load across some of our application servers. The basic configuration looks like:

```
listen  dev 0.0.0.0:15984
    balance roundrobin
    server  dev1 dev1:5984 check
    server  dev2 dev2:5984 check
    server  dev3 dev3:5984 check
```

I'm performing some performance testing and wondering, does haproxy cache something in this configuration or just redirect the requests?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nope, HAproxy does not cache anything.